# Fetch data from mysql to android using PHP

Tags: php, android

I am very new to android application development and I have a simple android application for contest.

Each day I put a question and 4 answers in the mysql table using php to a remote server.From there I want to display the question and options in the android dialog box.

[image]

This is my Activity.java file

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HelloFMActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogbox);
                radioButtongroub= (RadioGroup)dialog.findViewById(R.id.radiogroub);
                dialog.setTitle("My Question ?");
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                Button okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.sendbtn);
                Button closeButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.closebtn);
```

This my dialogbox.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#800080" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/namelayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Option 1 " />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="option 2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Option 3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Option 4" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroub"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/namelayout"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sms1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sms2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sms3"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sms4"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radiogroub"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Send" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/closebtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Close" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: At first you need to learn , How can android communicate with php web api. Please check it and learn about then you do your own work. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm